# Pass data from RecyclerView element to new activity (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have RecyclerView and write code to start activity by clicking on element in recycler view

I have this code in Adapter

```
void OnItemClick(int position)
    {
        _context.StartActivity(new Intent(_context, typeof(Tours_detail)));
    }
```

I need to pass data to Activity. How I can do this?

For example with PutExtra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add data into your intent. I think that PutExtra function will do the work for you

```
var intent = new Intent(_context, typeof(Tours_detail);
intent.PutExtra("name", "value");
_context.StartActivity(intent);
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/